# How to reload a JQuery Script after a time interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I have a web page with JQuery which reads a json file and display tags on the webpage and also provide user a possibility to add the tags manually.
Below is the java script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function, 2000);
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1058x', function(res){
        $.each(res.data, function(key, val){
        $("<span class='tag label label-info'><span>"+val.tag+"</span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span></span>").appendTo('.list')
        });
    }); 

        $('#addButton').click(function() {
            var toAdd=$('input[name=checkbox]').val();
            var tag = "<span class='tag label label-info'><span>"+toAdd+"</span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span></span>"
            $(tag).appendTo('.list');
        });


        $('.list').on('click','span',function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });

    });
```

And below is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="border: 1px solid">
        <h2 class="text-center">Tag suggestions:</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <p><br></p>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center">
          Refresh Rate:
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 pull-left">
          <input type="range" min="0" max="60" step="1" value="30" style="width:85%" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 pull-left">
          <input class="text-center" id="rangeValue" type="text" value="30" style="width:25%;border:2px solid #456879; border-radius:4px;" /> &nbsp; Minutes
          </div>
          </div>
          <br><br>
          <div class="text-center">
          <div class="list">
          </div>
          </div>

          <br><br>
          <div class="text-center">
          <form id="tagInput">
          <input type='text' name='checkbox' style="border:2px solid #456879; border-radius:10px; height: 26px; width: 230px;"/>
          </form>
          <br><br>
          <button id="addButton" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

I have also created a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/amitJS/xncp92ho/12/).
What I want now to refresh the javascript every two minutes. so that it can read the file every two minutes and display tags again without reloading the page again and again but just the tags. I would highly appriciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use setInterval or settimeout to fetch the values every 2000ms. (I can see that setInterval is used). Just define a proper function and use it/ Let us know what is the challenge you are facing ?

Comment: `setInterval(function, 2000);` is a syntax error...

Comment: I have tried to implement the setInterval as per @sigorilla solution's and it worked the only problem I am facing is that it is appending everytime tags to previously added tags. I want that when it reads JSON file again it should delete previously written tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your script:

```js
var load = function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4skih', function (res) {
    $.each(res.data, function (key, val) {
        addTag(val.tag, key);
    });
  });
};

var init = function () {
    load();
 
    $('#addButton').on('click', function () {
        var $input = $('input[name=checkbox]');
        var toAdd = $.trim($input.val());
        if (toAdd !== '') { // check value.
            addTag(toAdd);
            $input.val(''); //clear input after add.
        }
    });
    $('.list').on('click', 'button', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  
    setInterval(load, 2000 * 60); // Loading data each 2 min.
};

$(document).ready(init);

// Add tag to html.
var addTag = function (tag) {
    $("<div><button class='tag'>" + tag + "</button></div>").appendTo('.list');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="list">
    </div>
    </div>
           
          <br><br>
          <div class="text-center">
          <input type='text' name='checkbox' />
          <br><br>
          <button id="addButton" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @siorilla, there is only one problem that its appending the tags which after each 2 mins. I want previous tags to be removed when writing again after two minutes. I have tried to edit again your js code above creating a remove Tag function separately but it does not work. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Hm, you can add `$('.list').html('');` at the beginning of the `load` function. This code will erase all tags from the list.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 120000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to fetch data periodically, I guess you wanted to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1058x', function (res) {
      $.each(res.data, function (key, val) {
        $("<span class='tag label label-info'><span>" + val.tag + "</span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span></span>").appendTo('.list')
      });
    }, 1000 * 120);
  });
});
```

As soon as document is ready, you invoke function every 2 minutes.

Comment: I tried the above solution given by @sigorilla which is kinda similiar to yours but what it does it keeps appending tags but I want to delete previously written tags every time it reloads the JSON file.